# infect serverx.exe virus help me

Tags: virus

my computer infected with serverx.exe virus and 
it couldn't remove form my local area network

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 1):

After performing a little bit of reasearch for you, it looks like Serverx.exe is not a very advanced virus.

Simply restart your computer in safe mode and locate the `serverx.exe` file and delete it.

You may also want to run [Microsoft / Sysinternal Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and delete all traces of it.

Lastly, [take a look here for some general advice](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/100370#100370) on recovering your computer from malware attacks.